# Combining RWST and IO

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I needed to do an IO operation inside an RWS, so I decided to combine an RWST with an IO monad. Although everything works fine, I can't get the logs from the outer monad.

This is what I currently have:

```
newtype VM2 a = VM2{
    unwrapVM :: RWST () () () IO a } 
deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)

runVmEval :: VM2 a -> IO () 
runVmEval m = do 
                evalRWST (run) () ()
                putStrLn $ "End"

test :: IO () 
test = do
         putStrLn "Start"
         runVmEval $ return ()

run :: RWST () [String] () IO () 
run = do 
        x <- lift getLine
        tell $ [x]
        lift (print x)
```

This is what I would like to do:

```
runVmEval :: VM2 a -> IO ()
runVmEval m = do
    let w = evalRWST (run) () ()
    putStrLn $ snd w
    putStrLn $ "End"
```

This obviously fails, as w is of type `IO ((), [String])`

I have also tried the following:

```
runVmEval :: VM2 a -> IO ()
runVmEval m = do
    let (a,w) = evalRWST (run) () ()
    putStrLn $ "End"
    mapM_ (putStrLn) $ snd w
```

But I keep getting the aforementioned type error...

Any ideas?

Comment: Why give `runVmEval` an argument that it doesn't use?

Comment: That's because I am still a newbie and I was trying to wrap my mind around the concept of stacking monad transformers, so this code is really messy. Anyway, you are right, rumVmEval is more than enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use bind instead of `let`.

```
runVmEval m = do
    (a,w) <- evalRWST run () ()
    putStrLn "End"
    mapM_ putStrLn w
```

Comment: I had literally tried everything for the past 2 hours. Thanks a lot Daniel!